# I want to show Data of all year filter by month in Vue Js and Backend Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, laravel-filters

I am using Laravel as a Backend and Vue.js as a Frontend.

I'm creating an API to get all the data without any filter based on Month.

So, how can i show data for their Month in a Vue.js template?

For example, I have Data:

- for March: show row of created date in March
- for April: Show row of created date in April

What is best way to show them? or i have to create a different method of different months in controller.

Please Advise
Thanks

Comment: send selected date range to laravel and parse it using carbon. Then you can easily search then date, number of week, number of month and much more and after that you can query your eloquent to find records within that time range.

Answer (score 2):

I am also having same condition where I select date range from calendar on vue and send that dates to laravel and then parse those dates in laravel using Carbon and find eloquent records using those date range.

```
$query = Payment::query();

if($request->filled('startDate')){
      $query = $query->where('date','>=',Carbon::parse($request->startDate)->toDateTimeString());
}
if($request->filled('endDate')){
     $query = $query->where('date','<=',Carbon::parse($request->endDate)->toDateTimeString());
}
return response()->json(['payments' => $query->get()]; //return in format that you want
```

We can also return date range from start and end date using carbon

```
function findDateRange($request)
{
    $carbon = '\Carbon\Carbon';
    $dateRange = 'Invalid Date Range';
    if($request->filled('startDate') &&  $request->filled('endDate')){
        $differenceInDays = $carbon::parse($request->startDate)->diffInDays($carbon::parse($request->endDate));
        if($differenceInDays < 7){
            $dateRange = 'Week '. $carbon::parse($request->startDate)->weekOfYear .'<br>'. $carbon::parse($request->startDate)->format(authUser()->date_format) .' - '.$carbon::parse($request->endDate)->format(authUser()->date_format);
        }elseif($differenceInDays > 6 && $differenceInDays < 32){
            $dateRange = $carbon::parse($request->startDate)->format('F Y');
        }elseif($differenceInDays > 32 && $differenceInDays < 366){
            $dateRange = $carbon::parse($request->startDate)->format('Y');
        }
    }
    return $dateRange;
}
```

this will return date range like  shown in image
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: How you are sending from vue js.

Comment: Like for each month l

Comment: I am sending just start and end date and carbon is telling me that it is march or april.

Comment: Ok Thanks. Or if i want load data on  dom load than how can send param to server based on month.

Comment: sorry i know this is very basic questin but i am new to Vue js

Comment: on load we usually get full records. So do not send any dates just fetch all records. when user select any date range then send it and fetch records using those dates. the code that I wrote at start is checking if dates are available then find records using those records otherwise fetch all.

Comment: yes i know how to fetch based on user select. But like if i want have predefined area of each month than how to show data based on that month.

Comment: suppose you want to get records of current month  then get month using js and send in api call. You can easily get start and end date of current month as however you want using js Date

Comment: So i have to make different method in vue js for each month or it be done with one method ?

Comment: just one method will return you the date range of your current month

Comment: For each 12 month have to create a different array like January and Feb with one method ?
or can we passes any Params to method on Load